Rename of a file do not work in Assembler
I would like to rename a file, but there is no error and my assembler code do not rename the file from ww.txt to ww2.txt. Why?
I made different tests with the @data handler or mov the ax into the dx register.
; TASM 7.1

.MODEL TINY
.STACK 100h
.CONST
  HW      DB      "Hallo Welt!$"
  CCW      DB      "TEST$"
  FILEX     DB  "d:\WW.TXT",0
  FILEY     DB  "d:\WW2.TXT",0
  Daten1 DB "Daten1",0
  handle dw 0
.CODE

start: 
  ; Text 1 Output
  MOV AX,@data
  MOV DS, AX
  MOV DX, OFFSET HW
  MOV AH, 09H
  INT 21H

  ; Text 2 Output
  MOV AX,@data
  MOV DS, AX
  MOV DX, OFFSET CCW
  MOV AH, 09H
  INT 21H

  ; Create File
  MOV AX, @data
  MOV DS, AX
  MOV CX, 0
  MOV DX, OFFSET FILEX
  MOV AH, 3CH
  INT 21h

  ; Rename file - do not work - why?
  MOV AX, @data
  MOV DS, AX
  MOV DX, OFFSET FILEX
  MOV AX, @data
  MOV DS, AX
  MOV DI, OFFSET FILEY
  MOV ah, 56h
  int 21h

  ; Program beenden
  MOV AH, 4Ch
  INT 21H
end start


You don't need to keep reloading DS. However you should load ES since int21/56 expects that. It also returns an error code, check that. You might also need to close the file.

Thank you so much. I add MOV ES, AX 4 lines and it worked. How I know when I load ES too?

Whatever DOS reference you use should contain that. For example helppc says "ES:DI = pointer to new ASCIIZ path/filename"
